# Applying aggregation with multiple arguments

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                       "person":[i for i in range(5)]*2, 
                       "val_1":np.random.randn(10),
                       "val_1_entry": ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'], 
                       "val_2":np.random.randn(10),
                       "val_2_entry": ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
                      }).sort_values('person')

   person     val_1 val_1_entry     val_2 val_2_entry
0       0 -0.174681           a  0.464660           b
5       0  0.049361           f  1.332204           g
1       1  1.113805           b  0.261678           c
6       1 -0.847422           g -0.272731           h
2       2 -0.583784           c  1.815190           d
7       2 -1.101540           h -1.660562           i
3       3  0.919850           d  0.651178           e
8       3  1.309287           i  0.776856           j
4       4  1.395888           e  0.180980           f
9       4  0.699365           j -1.108057           k
```

For each person, I want to aggregate the data, taking the min and max (and possibly some arbitrary value), and take the corresponding value. If I do a simple aggregation where I take the min and max, that works fine...

```
df_proc = (df
           .groupby('person')
           .agg({'val_1': ['max', 'min'],
                 'val_2': ['max', 'min']}))

           val_1               val_2          
             max       min       max       min
person                                        
0       0.049361 -0.174681  1.332204  0.464660
1       1.113805 -0.847422  0.261678 -0.272731
2      -0.583784 -1.101540  1.815190 -1.660562
3       1.309287  0.919850  0.776856  0.651178
4       1.395888  0.699365  0.180980 -1.108057
```

but what I'd like is to have is the corresponding entries in the same row as their own variable.

```
           val_1               val_2           val_1_entry val_2_entry
             max       min       max       min         max         min
person                                        
0       0.049361 -0.174681  1.332204  0.464660           f           a
1       1.113805 -0.847422  0.261678 -0.272731           b           g
2      -0.583784 -1.101540  1.815190 -1.660562           c           h
3       1.309287  0.919850  0.776856  0.651178           i           d
4       1.395888  0.699365  0.180980 -1.108057           e           j
```

and so on.

If I could use a lambda where I'd return the value in one field corresponding to the index of another element, but I'm having a hard time seeing how to use aggregations over multiple columns.

Another approach could be to applying filters to the data, for each group, selecting the rows with the max and min and then spreading out the data, but I'm not quite sure how to do that; `query` doesn't work with grouped objects, and filter gives me a `df.groupby('person').filter(lambda x: x['val_1'] == x['val_1']min())` gives me an error about getting a series while expecting a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using apply() on the groups. Assuming df is defined as above, this will spit out the stated desired output:

```
val_cols = ['val_1', 'val_2']
def minmax(data):
    mins, maxs = [], []
    for vc in val_cols:
        data= data.sort(vc)  # use sort_values() with newer Pandas version
        mins.append(pd.Series(data.iloc[0][[vc, '%s_entry' % vc]], name='min')) 
        maxs.append(pd.Series(data.iloc[-1][[vc, '%s_entry' % vc]], name='max'))
    min = pd.concat(mins)
    max = pd.concat(maxs)
    return pd.DataFrame([min, max])
df.groupby('person').apply(minmax).unstack(-1)
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer. Unfortunately, I realized I made an error in my description, in that the value entry field selected should be the same for both min and max (that is, say, `val_2_entry` shouldn't be there, and I should be selecting from `val_1_entry` for the min/max of `val_1` and `val_2`. A direct application of your solution is giving me a bit of a headache (because of duplicate indexes), but it's much farther than I've gotten on my own, so hopefully I'll be able to adapt your solution.

Comment: Ok, it wasn't hard, just apply a rename when the series was created. Thank you again.